# Simple Sql queries on table: AVG, COUNT, VIEW

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have now imported a csv file to a table in a database in Mysql workbench. The table consist of lots of weather data, recorded at different times and at a few different weather stations listed in a column, at the once.
But now I am struggling with some queries.
Hope this is understandable:

-First I want to make a query that gives me the average value of the air_temp (1 of the columns) for each weather station. Obviously I have tried with the AVG() command, but it does not seem to work.

-Secondly I want to make a query that shows the number of measurements for each weather station. I have tried using the COUNT command.

-Thirdly I want to create a query that gives the name of all stations that have at least one row of values for the column
wind_gust, e.g. at least one row not being NULL FOR wind_gust column.

-Lastly the biggest task maybe I want to create a view containing the mean value for all the columns for each station ID.

Appreciate some tips and help to help me learning a bit more about sql queries.

Thanks!

[Image of the table to do queries on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HUwr.jpg)

Comment: It would very much help to see the table with some sample data. For example, there are many reasons why AVG() could fail, but we don't know the database schema or the query so very hard to tell what went wrong. Kind of saying "my car is broken, it's blue, how do I fix it?"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We prefer posts that ask just one question. And a [mcve] is much more useful than "does not seem to work."  Think of us as the rubber duck in [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and you can't go too far wrong. Please ask another, more specific, question.

Comment: Ahh okay, sorry was my first post. Added a picture of the table now, and will show more of my coding next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are your queries!

- First I want to make a query that gives me the average value of the air_temp (1 of the columns) for each weather station. Obviously I have tried with the AVG() command, but it does not seem to work.

```
select station_id, avg(air_temp) as avg_air_temp
from table
group by station_id
```

- Secondly I want to make a query that shows the number of measurements for each weather station. I have tried using the COUNT command.

```
select station_id, count(*) as num_measurements
from table
group by station_id
```

- Thirdly I want to create a query that gives the name of all stations that have at least one row of values for the column wind_gust, e.g. at least one row not being NULL FOR wind_gust column.

```
select distinct station_id
from table
where wind_gust is not null
```

- Lastly the biggest task maybe I want to create a view containing the mean value for all the columns for each station ID.

```
select station_id
     , avg(column1) as avg_column1
     , avg(column2) as avg_column2
     , avg(column3) as avg_column3
     , avg(column4) as avg_column4
from table
group by station_id
```